# How do I post json data in an rspec feature test powered by Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

### Short question

I need to post JSON in feature tests, something like in my controller tests:

```
post '/orders.json', params.to_json, format: :json
```

But I need to do it in feature tests, and `page.driver.post` only posts form data. How do I post JSON in Capybara?

### Long Explanation

I have a (non-Rails) app (let's call it the planet) that posts JSON to my rails app (call it a star) to create a record, and then forwards the user to the url for the show action.

I'm creating a feature spec, but since the first interaction isn't part of the Rails, app, I need to mock it using JSON.

I've been using this:

```
page.driver.post '/orders.json', params.to_json
```

But this seems to post as a form, whereas my planet application posts JSON. This leads to some really funky parameter problems, where parsing JSON gives me different params from form-data.

How do I post JSON in Capybara?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, turns out that it just isn't possible with Capybara. See [Thomas Walpole](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47603680/3970701)'s answer for more details.

As a workaround, I used `httparty`:

```
require 'httparty'

RSpec.feature 'Checkouts', type: :feature do
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'http://localhost:3000'

  private

  def checkout_with(cart)
    post orders_path(format: :json).to_s,
         body:    cart.to_json,
         headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - you don't

Capybara is designed to emulate a user for feature tests. Hence why the `post` method is driver specific (page.driver.xxx) and really isn't intended for use directly by tests.  A user can't just submit a POST without a page to submit it from.  Therefore, if you do actually need to test this via feature tests, the best solution is to create a small test app that provides a page you can have Capybara visit which will automatically (or on button click, etc) have the browser make the AJAX post to the app under test and handle the response.

Comment: Yes, but how do I do this anyways? Even if it's done via `Rack::Test` or `Httparty`

Comment: @amingilani Create a small sinatra app (or equivalent) that loads a page which does the POST you want, and tell Capybara to visit whatever port you mount that app on.  Note, this only makes sense if you actually have to test this through feature tests and can't just test it through some less abstracted type of test (controller, request, etc)